# Add multiple columns with string data from another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

This program places a name in Column E from a string in Column D. How can I introduce a Column F for strings with 2 names? Could Column G work for a 3rd?

```
Sub name1() 'Main Program

Dim nmArr()
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("D2") '## This is the STARTING cell

'## This is the list of names built as an array
nmArr = Array("Christy", "Kari", "Sue", "Clayton", "DanK", "Gawtry", Holly", "John", "Matt", "Dustin", "David")
Do
    For i = LBound(nmArr) To UBound(nmArr)
        If InStr(1, cl.Value, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = nmArr(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    '## Get a handle on the NEXT cell
    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until Trim(cl.Text) = vbNullString
outcome1

End Sub
```

@Scottcramer : Here is what my data looks like...

[image]

Comment: So let me get this straight, you have a column that includes first names, last names and possibly a middle name?  And you want to pull the various names out and populate the next three columns with those each in their own cell?  Can you show some example data?  There may be an easier way than the route your currently following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split the data on the `,` then test each part if it is in the array and output each name in either E,G,H

```
Sub name1dd() 'Main Program

Dim nmArr()
Dim i As Long, j As Integer
Dim cl As Range
Dim splArr() As String
Dim nm As Variant

Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("D2") '## This is the STARTING cell

'## This is the list of names built as an array
nmArr = Array("Christy", "Kari", "Sue", "Clayton", "DanK", "Gawtry", "Holly", "John", "Matt", "Dustin", "David")

Do
    j = 1
    splArr = Split(cl.Value, ",")
    For Each nm In splArr
        For i = LBound(nmArr) To UBound(nmArr)
            If InStr(1, nm, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                cl.Offset(0, j).Value = nmArr(i)
                If j = 1 Then
                    j = j + 2
                Else
                    j = j + 1
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next nm

    '## Get a handle on the NEXT cell
    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until Trim(cl.Text) = vbNullString
outcome1

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Compile Error: For each control variable on arrays must be variant?

Comment: That totally did it, very impressive. Thank you kindly. You have no idea how much that helped and how much it help me understand the whole process.

Comment: Sorry, new here! Thanks again!

Comment: Didn't use formulas but I guess still worth upvote =P

Comment: @findwindow almost suggested it, till I noticed that they call another sub from this one.

Comment: Food for thought here. What if I needed to have the list of names be ranked by order. Like all the Sue's would be first, Kari's second etc...

Comment: @JSt flip the two inner loops.  Loop first through the nmarr then through splarr.  This will put them in order of the Array of names entered.  Put that in the order you want the names to appear.

Comment: [For i = LBound(nmArr) To UBound(nmArr)] Above [For Each nm In splArr]??

Comment: @JSt yes and you will need to flip the `Next i` with the `Next nm` also.

Comment: like a charm, simply amazing